# How to copy files to correct program files folder using batch?

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a simple batch file which copies a file from one directory to program files\my folder?

If the OS is Windows 64-bit then I want to copy to `C:\Program Files (x86)\My Folder` or Windows 32-bit then `C:\Program Files\My Folder`.

Comment: Did you look at any tutorials for writing batch files? Did you try anything at all yet?

Comment: figure out the command line for it, then stuff that exact command line into a .bat file. it's not that hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%ProgramFiles%`, and let the operating system figure out where the files need to go.

```
copy C:\MyFiles\*.* "%ProgramFiles%\My Folder\"
```